# Jquery clone and rename input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following:

```
<!-- group clone //-->
<div class="section">
    <div class="parent row infoOn">
        <div class="validGroup">
            <a title="remove" class="iconClose" href="#">remove</a>
                <div class="grouping">
                    <div class="clearfix valid">
                        <label>Name<span class="iconReq">&nbsp;</span>:</label>
                        <input type="password" class="text inpButton" name="items[0].first">
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <label>Email<span class="iconReq">&nbsp;</span>:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="text inpButton" name="items[0].first">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row addControl">
            <a href="#" class="button">Add</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- group clone //-->
```

and jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    // Control clone
    $('div.addControl a.button').click(function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var parent = $(this).closest('.section').find('.parent:last');
        var parentInput = parent.clone();
        parentInput.find("input").val("");
        parent.after(parentInput);
    });
    $('div.validGroup a.iconClose').live('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).closest('.section').find('.parent').length > 1){
            $(this).closest('div.parent').remove();
        }
    });
    reflesh();
});
```

1. clicking the "Add" button removes
   values from input fields and clones
   the group (2 input fields).
2. clicking "remove" link removes
   group

Question: how would I change it so that when adding OR removing a new group, input fields would be renamed to `name="items[INDEX].first"` and `name="items[INDEX].last"`

For example. when there's only one "group", input fields would have names:

- `name="items[0].first"`
- `name="items[0].last"`

if I add another one, the new one would have

- `name="items[1].first"`
- `name="items[1].first"`

and so on.
When I remove the first one (one with `items[0].first`), the second one's input names would be modified from `"items[1].first"` to `items[0].first`.

here is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
var size = parseInt($('.form .section .parent').size());
$('.form .section .parent').each(function(index){
    $(this).find('input.text').each(function(){
        $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace($(this).attr("name").match(/\[[0-9]+\]/), "["+index+"]"));
    });
    if (size > 1) { $(this).find('a.iconClose').show(); }else{ $(this).find('a.iconClose').hide(); }
});
```

Comment: Instead of `replace($(this).attr("name").match(/\\[[0-9]+\\]/), "["+index+"]"))` you could use `replace(/\\[\d+\\]/,"["+index+"]") ` directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.add-more').on('click',function(){
var newelement= $(".form-content").eq(0).clone();
var num = $('.form-content').length;
var newNum = num + 1;
newelement.find('input').each(function(i){
   $(this).attr('name',$(this).attr('name')+newNum);
   $(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id')+newNum); 
});
$('.form-content').last().after(newelement);
});
```

Comment: While a code-only answer is indeed an answer, a bit of explanation (why the OP's code did not work, what is the general idea behind your code, important points, warnings, ...) could make it a *better* answer.